# Updating a State Array in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update a State in an Array using prevstate but i can't find my problem can any body help?

I want to change the firmName which is located in the userCompany Array.

This is where i am trying tu update the state

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={userCompany.firmName}
     onChange={(e) => this.setState(prevState => ({
     userCompany: [...prevState.userCompany, userCompany.firmName]
}))}/>
```

I set my State in the render funktion like so

```
const {
            openTab, firstName, lastName, email, city, country, street, plz,
            streetNumber, phoneCountryPre, phoneNumber, phonePre, message, messageType, active, userCompany
        } = this.state;
```

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve? I'm asuming you want the user to input a Firm Name and this input should be pushed in an array you defined in the state, is my assumption acurate enough?

Comment: yes i have an arry called userCompany which is in also in an array and i want to update the state firmname which is located in userCompany after a user chnaged it in the input field

Comment: how many companies a user should have? I'm sorry I'm asking these questions.I do not want to give you a misleading answer

Comment: only one but there are more values like companyPhone in the array userCompany

Comment: then you should have it as an object not as an array. e.g(userCompany:{firmName:"Something".....}

Comment: i am not sure but here how my userCompany looks like as a jason

userCompany:
countryPrePhone: "+43"
fax: "251425"
firmDetail: "nice"
firmName: "Test"
id: 48
landlinePhone: "1252425"
mobilePhone: "12524515"
owner: "/api/users/162"
uidNr: 1254251
websiteUrl: "test.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use userCompany as an object not as an aryy

```
const {userCompany:{firmName:"Something"}}=this.state

<input type="text" defaultValue={this.state.userCompany.firmName}
 onChange={(e) => this.setState({
 ...this.state,userCompany:{...this.state.userCompany, firmName:e.target.value})}/>
```

but it also worth mentioning, use hooks instead of class components. Read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

please add in input follow values:

```
<input type="text" value={firstName} onChange={*setStata function*}/>
```

or you not incorrect values;

```
userCompany: [...prevState.userCompany, **userCompany.firstName**]
```